# Network card location

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, hp, hp-proliant

I am generally familiar with `hpacucli` and `hpasmcli` but how do I determine in which slot a network card is installed? I need to be able to map to and from the slot and the MAC (and from there to the interface as Linux sees it), but `SHOW SERVER` only gives me the MACs of the onboard ports. Thanks!

Also I know the technique for remotely illuminating a drive light for the benefit of a technician in the datacentre for a hotswap - is there anything like this for network cards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to using the ID light identify a server or specific disk the `ethtool` utility has the `-p` switch:

> **-p --identify**
>                 Initiates adapter-specific action intended to enable an operator
>                 to  easily  identify  the  adapter by sight.  Typically this involves blinking one or more LEDs on the specific network port.

Alternatively the /sys directory under Linux will have the correct mapping to PCI ports (in this case two on-board NIC's and a second dual-port PCI card):

```
# find /sys | grep -e eth.*/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/net/eth1/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/net/eth2/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/net/eth3/address
```

Comment: Once you have the PCI address, you can get the slot from `hplog`. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaius ``ethtool -i eth0`` will show the PCIe-ID.